# How can I debug my Python implementation of replace_ending()?

Tags: python, string, function, if-statement

Project statement:

> The `replace_ending` function replaces the old string in a sentence with the new string, but only if the sentence ends with the old string. If there is more than one occurrence of the old string in the sentence, only the one at the end is replaced, not all of them.
>
> For example, `replace_ending("abcabc", "abc", "xyz")` should return `abcxyz`, not `xyzxyz` or `xyzabc`. The string comparison is case-sensitive, so `replace_ending("abcabc", "ABC", "xyz")` should return `abcabc` (no changes made).

Here is my code:

```
def replace_ending(sentence, old, new):
    # Check if the old string is at the end of the sentence 
    if ___:
        # Using i as the slicing index, combine the part
        # of the sentence up to the matched string at the 
        # end with the new string
        i = ___
        new_sentence = ___
        return new_sentence

    # Return the original sentence if there is no match 
    return sentence

print(replace_ending("It's raining cats and cats", "cats", "dogs")) 
# Should display "It's raining cats and dogs"
print(replace_ending("She sells seashells by the seashore", "seashells", "donuts")) 
# Should display "She sells seashells by the seashore"
print(replace_ending("The weather is nice in May", "may", "april")) 
# Should display "The weather is nice in May"
print(replace_ending("The weather is nice in May", "May", "April")) 
# Should display "The weather is nice in April"
```

Comment: First, it's not clear what you want and what it's returning. So in your test cases, include current output also along with expected one.  And suggest you to go with regex and use re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0) of python.  https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Some useful information for you: here we want questions to have useful titles. This helps current readers see if they can help you, and it helps future readers see if your issue might help them with their problem. A title of `I am bit confused can anyone please help me out to find the solution of this problem?` contains no useful information at all, but imagine that was the title of all 19.2 millions questions on the site - it would be unusable.

Comment: Also, the first two paragraphs look like a problem statement that has been pasted from a homework or online code challenge. That is fine - we are happy to help with code challenges here - but it is a good idea to use quote formatting, so readers can follow what you have written personally, and what has been written by someone else. This makes it easier to work out what you understand and what you don't understand.

Answer (score -1):

You should use [slicing](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-index-and-slice-strings-in-python-3) from the end of the "sentence" string, in order to check the last sub-string that matches with the "old" string.
Using string slicing to fill the blanks in the question that you have described:

```
def replace_ending(sentence, old, new):
    # Check if the old string is at the end of the sentence 
    if old == sentence[-len(old):]:
        # Using i as the slicing index, combine the part
        # of the sentence up to the matched string at the 
        # end with the new string
        i = len(sentence)-len(old)
        new_sentence = sentence[:i] + new
        return new_sentence

    # Return the original sentence if there is no match 
    return sentence
```